# Intercepting all outgoing HTTPS requests from machine and redirecting it

Tags: http, redirection, localhost

I want to intercept all HTTP requests in that the user is sending and redirect them to my own localhost:5000, where changes will be made to the request, it will send it to the intended server recipient, and the response will be returned to the user.

I did some research on using the hosts file for redirecting, but it only allows specific ip's to be redirected and wildcards are not allowed.

I also wish to leverage a Python script to enable/disable this intercepting (but that's another question, I only wish to learn the method of which the universal redirecting happens)

thanks!

Comment: it works kind of like a VPN in the way that it redirects all outgoing traffic to another server (obviously in this case the VPN is redirecting it to an external server in a different country but I'm just trying to redirect it to my locally-running web server)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are perhaps looking to create your own
[Proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) :

> a proxy server is a server application that acts as an intermediary between a client requesting a resource and the server providing that resource

You should probably look for an open-source proxy server and modify it
to do your modifications. For example see
[Px](https://github.com/genotrance/px).

(Just to remark that this is not an easy project.)